# Print name of Handler class in C++

Tags: c++, class, ns2

I am new to C++ and trying to understand some code (packet scheduling in NS2).
At some point a packet passes through the following code:

```
    void 
    Scheduler::dispatch(Event* p, double t) 
    { 
            if ((t < clock_) && (p->uid_ != 0)) { 
                    fprintf(stderr, "ns: scheduler going backwards in time from %f to %f.\n", clock_, t); 
                    dumpq(); 
            } 
            if (p->uid_ != 0) { 
                    clock_ = t; 
                    p->uid_ = -p->uid_; // being dispatched 
                    p->handler_->handle(p); // dispatch                     
            } else { 
                    fprintf(stderr, "Warning: discarding Event without an a valid id\n"); 
            } 
    }
```

My question: is there an easy way for me to find out here what the class of `handler_` is and where I should look for `handle(p)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there an easy way for me to find out here what the class of handler_ is and where I should look for handle(p)?

Set a breakpoint at `p->handler_->handle(p);` and step into it.

Or, in `gdb`, do `info symbol p->handler_->handle`.

Or pass `nullptr` into `handle` hoping that it crashes and dumps core or displays a stack trace.

You can also get object's class *mangled* name like `typeid(*p->handler_).name()`.